# Differences in displaying currency

Tags: c#, wpf

While playing around with formatting a string with a currency value, I noticed a difference in how WPF displays it.

When formatting a `decimal` value in `XAML`, WPF displays it as `5,99 €`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Total, StringFormat={}{0:C}}"/>
return 5.99m;
```

When I format in code behind, it displays it as `€ 5,99`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalString}"/>
return string.Format("{0:C}", 5.99m);
```

Is this a bug?

I got Windows 10, targeting .NET version is 4.5.2.

Comment: Which country? On my german Windows 10, `string.Format` returns "5,99 €"

Comment: @Clemens Belgium. My settings in windows are also correct so that won't be the problem I think.

Answer (score 1):

When setting the `StringFormat` of a Binding, WPF does not use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`, but just `en-US` by default, or the value you specify by setting the element's (or its parent's) `Language` property. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1062160/1136211) for more details.

On the other hand, `string.Format` does use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`. And how that exactly behaves with regard to formatting currencies is configurable by the user.

For example the currency pattern is controlled by the registry value `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\iCurrency` and can be set in the Control Panel (sorry it's German):

[image]

So you might just change that setting to achieve the formatting behaviour you get from StringFormat.