# How to bind a property both ways on a control inside a DataGridTemplateColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have an `ObservableCollection` of `DataPoint` objects. That class has a `Data` property. I have a `DataGrid`. I have a custom UserControl called `NumberBox`, which is a wrapper for a `TextBox` but for numbers, with a `Value` property that is bind-able (or at least is intended to be).

I want the `DataGrid` to display my `Data` in a column `NumberBox`, so the value can be displayed and changed. I've used a `DataGridTemplateColumn`, bound the `Value` property to `Data`, set the `ItemsSource` to my `ObservableCollection`.

When the underlying `Data` is added or modified, the `NumberBox` updates just fine. However, when I input a value in the box, the `Data` doesn't update.

I've found answers suggesting to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Firstly, not sure on what I should implement it. Secondly, I tried to implement it [thusly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) on both my `DataPoint` and my `NumberBox`. I've found answers suggesting to add `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChange` to my `Value` binding. I've tried both of these, separately, and together. Obviously, the problem remains.

Below is the bare minimum project I'm currently using to try to make this thing work. What am I missing?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window xmlns:BindingTest="clr-namespace:BindingTest" x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="Container" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sample Text" Width="100" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <BindingTest:NumberBox Value="{Binding Data}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="BTN" Click="Button_Click" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Check"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<DataPoint> Liste { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Liste = new ObservableCollection<DataPoint>();

        Container.ItemsSource = Liste;

        DataPoint dp1 = new DataPoint(); dp1.Data = 1;
        DataPoint dp2 = new DataPoint(); dp2.Data = 2;
        Liste.Add(dp1);
        Liste.Add(dp2);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BTN.Content = Liste[0].Data;
    }
}
```

DataPoint.cs

```
public class DataPoint
{
    public double Data { get; set; }
}
```

NumberBox.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingTest.NumberBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="28" d:DesignWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBox Name="Container" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

NumberBox.cs

```
public partial class NumberBox : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    public NumberBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private double _value;
    public double Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            Container.Text = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (ValueChanged != null) ValueChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Value",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(NumberBox),
        new PropertyMetadata(OnValuePropertyChanged)
    );

    public static void OnValuePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        double? val = e.NewValue as double?;
        (d as NumberBox).Value = val.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you tried `<BindingTest:NumberBox Value="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`?

Comment: @CorentinPane I already tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Quite a few things actually.

1. The CLR property of a dependency property should *only* get and set the value of the dependency property:

   ```
    public partial class NumberBox : UserControl
    {
        public NumberBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public double Value
        {
            get => (double)GetValue(ValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(NumberBox),
            new PropertyMetadata(0.0)
        );

        private void Container_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            Value = double.Parse(Container.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
   ```
2. The `TextBox` in the control should bind to the `Value` property:

   ```
    <TextBox Name="Container" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
             PreviewTextInput="Container_PreviewTextInput"/>
   ```
3. The mode of the binding between the `Value` and the `Data` property should be set to `TwoWay` and also, and this is because the input control is in the `CellTemplate` of the `DataGrid`, the `UpdateSourceTrigger` should be set to `PropertyChanged`:

   ```
    <local:NumberBox x:Name="nb" Value="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
   ```

Comment: This mostly works, however binding the Text is problematic because it seems to mess with parsing. When I type a decimal number, it seems to use English number format, which isn't how my system is set. (I've removed the PreviewTextInput event altogether, so it's not that line causing the issue).

Answer (score 0):

[mm8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69468077/6097447) pointed me in the right direction.

The two key missing elements were indeed:
to change the `TextBox` in NumberBox.xaml such as

```
<TextBox Name="Container"
     Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"
     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
    />
```

and to change the binding in MainWindow.xaml such as

```
...
<DataTemplate>
    <BindingTest:NumberBox 
        Value="{Binding Data, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</DataTemplate>
...
```

With these two modifications, both the `Value` and `Data` are being updated two-ways inside my `DataGridTemplaceColumn`.

Binding to the text however proved problematic. WPF apparently uses en-US culture no matter how your system is setup, which is *really* bad as this control deals with numbers. Using [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16583400/6097447) solves that problem, and now the correct decimal separator is recognised. In my case, I've added it in a static constructor for the same effect so NumberBox can be used in other applications as is.

```
static NumberBox()
{
    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

I've tested this in my test project, and then again tested the integration into my real project. As far as I can tell, it holds water, so I'll consider this question answered.