# WPF XAML StringFormat: Culture Workaround broken in C# 4.0?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, string-formatting

The work around...

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
 typeof(FrameworkElement), 
 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
  XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

...used to work till now (mentioned here: [StringFormat Localization issues in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringfomat-localization-problem/520334#520334)).

Instead till I ported my application from 3.5SP1 to 4.0, it was working. But now in 4.0 it stopped working again. Anybody experiencing this?

**EDIT:** It is now not even working in 3.5SP1. I think this has something to do with the installation of 4.0 as previously this was working.

It is not working by either adding the workaround or removing it. I even tried adding...

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ClearCachedData();
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

to `Window` constructor. This also didn't worked.

Comment: Perhaps MS have fixed the problem. What happens when you remove the work around completely? Does the code work as expected.

Comment: I added the info in the question.

Comment: Where are you overriding the LanguageProperty in your application? In your Application, Window, etc?

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Make sure you are overriding default value of `LanguageProperty` as early as possible. App's static constructor is the best bet. This is important because `BindingExpression` caches value of this property and does not reevaluate it afterwards for performance reasons.

**2.** What is your `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`? Are you sure it's the one you expect to see?

**3.** Overriding `Language` property metadata has no effect if you you specify `xml:lang` attribute somewhere upper in the tree. E.g. if you say:

```
<StackPanel xml:lang="it">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=C}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You'll get Italian currency no matter what you set in property metadata.

**4.** Overriding `Language` property metadata has no effect if you specify `ConverterCulture` property in binding. E.g. if you say: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat=C, ConverterCulture=ja}"/>` you'll get Japanese currency no matter what you set either in property metadata or in `xml:lang` attribute.

This behavior was not changed between frameworks as far as I know.

Hope this helps