# How to display localized text in a given language instead of the default one (when in design-mode)?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, localization, designmode

Currently I use `.resx` files to `localize` my application. The application forms' UI in `design mode` is displayed using the default culture (i.e. the `en-US` on my PC).

I want to change that culture to be another one, e.g. my local culture `vi-VN`, but don't know how to do that.

Please share if you know how to! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

just have a look at this

[How to set and change the culture in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041197/how-to-set-and-change-the-culture-in-wpf)

Comment: @Kumar: I need a solution used for design-mode. Thanks anyway.