# Culture is set to US in spite of PC region is set to UK

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

My PC's region is set to United Kingdom, but my silverlight's default culture is set to US.

I have found this excellent post explaining this would be the default behaviour in WPF and he also provides a solution for it.

[How to set and change the culture in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041197/how-to-set-and-change-the-culture-in-wpf)

Unfortunately as its usually the case I can't use this code in Silverlight. There is no OverrideMetadata method.  So my question is how do the Silverlight developers solve this problem?

Highly appreciated,

Comment: Don't know a lick about Silverlight development so I thought I'd pass this along while I was looking at other information about WPF localization: [Localizing Silverlight-based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838238(v=vs.95).aspx)

Comment: This happens to all Windows applications: because Windows is not localised to en-GB. Thus current culture is set to en-GB (dates, times, currency, ...) but UI culture for resources is en-US.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution, after weeks of research.

All you have to do in Silverlight is to put this into the top most window (container or Shell as in Prism)

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name);
```

Credit goes to this blog: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/08/11/stringformat-and-currentculture-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe one has to set the page's Language in the constructor directly after the `InitializeComponent();` call, it could be a good idea to create a `PageBase` class to do this but I have had difficulty getting the designer to like my Page base classes in the past