# How to add a thousands separator to a Binding of a Multibinding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, separator

So I have this XAML:

```
 <TextBlock.Text>
     <MultiBinding StringFormat="SomeText: &#x09;{0}&#x0a;SomeOtherText: &#x09;&#x09;{1}">
          <Binding Path="SomeBoundVar" />
          <Binding Path="AnotherBoundVar" StringFormat="{}{0:N2}" />
     </MultiBinding>
 </TextBlock.Text>
```

And I'd like to add a thousand separator to the 2nd binding (the StringFormat as above doesn't work).
How can I do that ? Or do I have to use a converter ?

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to create a new readonly property in your viewmodel with your format?

Comment: Couldn't you provide the formatting in the StringFormat on the MultiBinding? e.g. {1:N2} See the docs on [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @AndrewS: Almost. It works with {1:N0} thanks! Yet I still have the problem that it's using a comma as thousands separator while I'd like to use a dot as thousands separator (couldn't find anything on that on that page though).

Comment: You need to get your `Thread.Current.CurrentCulture` set accordingly to have whatever separator you want.

Comment: Well it didn't work by just setting the currentculture right - I also had to do this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041197/how-to-set-and-change-the-culture-in-wpf (1st answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had a same kind of issue and following is the way I fixed.

```
 <TextBlock>
       <TextBlock.Text>
           <MultiBinding StringFormat="{} Balance {0} : {1:##,#0.00}">
                  <Binding Path="Currency"/>
                  <Binding Path="Balance"/>
           </MultiBinding>
       </TextBlock.Text>
  </TextBlock>
```

Sample Result

**Balance AED : 2,456.45**