# Setting StringFormat for all DateTime objects globally independent of CultureInfo - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datetime-format, cultureinfo

Is there any way to set the `StringFormat` for all `DateTime` objects globally independently of the `CultureInfo` in my WPF Application?

I use bindings to this kind of objects from the whole application, like this:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
```

and I want to avoid having to add the `StringFormat` parameter to every binding.
I have tried to override the current culture `DateTimeFormat` parameters like this:

```
public void SetDateTimeFormat()
{
    culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;
    var newCulture = new CultureInfo(culture.Name);

    // Set desired date format here
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MMM/YYYY";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd/MMM/YYYY";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "dd/MMM/YYYY";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "dd/MMM/YYYY";
    newCulture.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd/MMM/YYYY";

    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;

    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

        var lang = System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(newCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        FrameworkContentElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
              typeof(System.Windows.Documents.TextElement),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(lang)
            );
}
```

But it doesn't works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set and change the culture in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041197/how-to-set-and-change-the-culture-in-wpf)

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question. My problem is that the label that shows the DateTime binding is not checking the DateTimeFormat patterns, or that my patterns are not set correctly. Also, my format should not be dependent of the current culture.

Comment: Overriding things in the current `CultureInfo` is an absolutely horrible idea that may blow up somewhere completely unexpected. Not only you're mutating global variables, you are mutating *someone else's* global variables - in this case, the framework's.

Comment: Ok @AntonTykhyy   Then how can ai accomplish this?

Comment: Use a custom binding like @mm8 suggests below.

Comment: Ok. I wanted to avoid modifying every line where the DateTime is binded but if this is the better solution, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to set the `StringFormat` for all `DateTime` objects globally independently of the `CultureInfo` in my WPF Application

A `DateTime` object doesn't have any `StringFormat` but a `Binding` has. You could create a custom `Binding` class:

```
public class MyCustomBinding : Binding
{
    public MyCustomBinding(string path)
        :base(path)
    {
        StringFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{local:MyCustomBinding Date}"/>
```

Or you could set the `Language` property of the element:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg" Language="en">
```

You could also do this globally for all elements in your `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        var culture = new CultureInfo("en");
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey, I did set the language property for all elements in my App. But the format displayed now is dd/MMM/YYYY hh:ss:mm and I want to remove the hh:ss:mm part. Is there any way to do this globally? I don't want to edit each binding.

Comment: Custom binding is the way to go - it's clear and declarative. Just call it something that will make the intent obvious, like `InvariantDateBinding`.

Answer (score 0):

in **app.xaml.cs**

```
  public App()
        {            
          
            CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);
            ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "M/d/yyyy";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        }
```