# WPF: Using culture specific separators in StringFormat

Tags: wpf, xaml, string-formatting

Is there a way to use culture specific characters in a WPF-StringFormat?
I'm trying to format a date to only show the month and the year separated by the culture specific ... uuh.. separator.

Here is my code:

```
Binding="{Binding StartDate.Value, StringFormat={}{0:MM.yyyy}, Converter={StaticResource StartEndDateTimeConverter}"
```

What would I use as a replacement for the dot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [StringFomat Localization problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringfomat-localization-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Instead of the '.' I should have been using the '/'-Symbol to separate the months from the years.