# "Invalid" datetime in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, mvvm, datagrid

I'm building an C# application using WPF/MVVM and I have some trouble using a DateTime in a DataGrid.

The column is defined as

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Start" Binding="{Binding StartDate, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy}" />
```

The code works fine with a date like 05-08-2011, which has a leading zero. But, when I try to enter a date without the leading zero (like 15-08-2011) the field won't validate. Why is that?

StartDate is of type DateTime.

Comment: Is that a literal example? How about "5-8-2011" ?  Anyway, you could try `d-M-yyyy`

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-problem/520334#520334

Comment: Also does `StringFormat={}{0:dd-MM-yyyy}}` help ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess should be the invalid culture. Probably the validation consider the month first, then the day. Check you PC settings.