# WPF localization problem

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, localization

I'm using this line to set the data binding localization:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

but I noticed that if I customize the language format in the control panel, for example by specifying another decimal separator, that change is not considered: the culture created is always the default.
Is there a way to solve this problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess,

for this we may need to redo the metatdata overriding in a window message handler for two specific windows messages

### Hex   Dec Symbol

0050  80  WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST

0051  81  WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE

See this code for handling windows messages in WPF

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/6b97a6de-0480-4339-8ed0-cb7cdb27bd83/

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: If I am correct, these messages signal the application when a language change occurs. I need reading the informations from the control panel during the application startup, so I think that these messages can't help. Tell me if I'm wrong. Thank you again.

Comment: But when you make these changes and say "Apply", only then you would want the changes to take effect isnt it? That is when we will receive the INPUTLANGCHANGE.

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a misunderstanding. I need to know the customizations made on global settings during my application startup and not when someone changes them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture`.

Comment: I can use it but the problem still remains, because the property IetfLanguageTag contains only the language code and not the informations saved in the control panel.

Comment: Did you have the same effect while changing the culture of the current thread?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set a ConverterCulture in the Binding.

First, add the namespace `xmlns:gl="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"`

and then use

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyPath, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"/>
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6423124/785529