# Setting Culture (en-IN) globally in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo, currentuiculture

I have an application, which is based for India, and I'm setting Culture as:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
```

The above code is called before the `Window.InitializeComponent()` method is called.

Still this is showing `$` as CurrencySymbol in all TextBoxes.

If I bind a TextBox as following, it shows `Rs.` as CurrencySymbol:

```
Text="{Binding Salary,Mode=TwoWay,StringFormat=C,ConvertCulture=en-IN}".
```

Comment: Also keep this in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-problem/520334#520334

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you will need to add the following.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

**Read more here:**

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting

Just to give you an example, this is how I initialize the Culture in my program, based on the user setting, but you can simply replace `UserSettings.DefaultCulture` and `UserSettings.Default.UICultrue` with your wanted Culture.

```
private static void InitializeCultures()
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSettings.Default.Culture))
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(UserSettings.Default.Culture);
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserSettings.Default.UICulture))
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(UserSettings.Default.UICulture);
    }

    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was missing the following line of code.  FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));  What actually this code do?

Comment: Take a look at the article I included, it includes a pretty good description of the issue.
http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting

Comment: Using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag` always uses Microsofts default values for the given culture and completely ignores changes made by the user. For example here in Germany default date format is 'dd.mm.yyyy' but I manually configured this to be ISO 8601 compliant: 'yyyy-mm-dd' but this is ignored within WPF apps most of the time (some special controls like xceeds Grid behave different/smarter).

Comment: Please note that the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag` is deprecated:  _"This property and the GetCultureInfoByIetfLanguageTag method are deprecated. Instead, you should use a the CultureInfo.Name property. IETF tags and names are identical."_. You should probably use `CultureInfo.Name` instead as indicated.

Answer (score 18):

For me just works, if i put this code to the OnStartup overrided method:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
      public App()
      {                
      }

      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
          var vCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");

          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = vCulture;
          Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = vCulture;
          CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = vCulture;
          CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = vCulture;

          FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
          typeof(FrameworkElement),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(                 
       XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

          base.OnStartup(e);
      }
}
```

Comment: And whats happen if i force en-US culture to the whole appliction, and my application run n a machine configured in spanish or any other culture not is en-US?

Comment: What you mean? The operating system language no make sense in this meaning. If you set en-US for the application, it stays and should run finely.

Answer (score 3):

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IN");

FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

This will switch the default language for the entire application. You’ll want to use this only in startup code as this setting can be applied only once per application. You can still override individual forms when necessary as below

```
this.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
```

> All WPF elements include a Language property that can be assigned and
>   determines the Culture that is used for formatting.

[Reference](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jun/14/WPF-Bindings-and-CurrentCulture-Formatting)

Answer (score 2):

To me just this worked, but in order to solve `ToString` and to make it work over the entire app, it's important to add it in constructor, not `OnStartup` etc, before you set up service container etc. otherwise it doesn't work in subsequent threads and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` still resolves to the default system `CultureInfo`.

```cs
public class App : Application
{
  public App() 
  {     
    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
    CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;

    FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(FrameworkElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(culture.IetfLanguageTag)));

     // should be before all this
     var host = Host
       .CreateDefaultBuilder()
       .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
       ...;        
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For my datagrid data i used below lines of code in App.xaml.cs & it worked ..
for de it displayed dot and En it displayed comma for 4 digit numbers.

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            
XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, there's another way of doing this, assuming that you're using a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Salary, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat='{}{0:C}', ConverterCulture='en-IN'}" />
```

Please bear in mind the single quotes are needed.