# Change only choosen columns to a custom format while remaining all columns stay intact in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, exceldatareader

**Edit:** I tried the `StringFormat`, it's working fine but the `DataGrid` showing only those columns that I've included in `<DataGrid.Columns>` Actually only `VALUE` and `DATE` should be formatted, **remaining columns should stay intact**. Means now I've to manually write `DataGridTextColumn` for each and every column? ( I have like 20+ columns, which can be tedious work!)

New to C# here. I have a DataGrid, which gets it's values from a DataTable. I use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to import from Excel to DataSet and eventually convert it to DataTable.

• How can I change the format of column `DATE` to system's default format?  (There will be different date format in different systems)
• How can I change the format of column `VALUE` to exactly 2 decimal places?

In VB.NET, It was simple : `DataGridView1.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"`

I cannot seem to get that work here. Please suggest me the best way to change those specific columns to the formats mentioned about. (without Performance degradation, saw some posts involving loops and converters)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format values in a Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4299329/format-values-in-a-datagrid)

Comment: You are looking for `StringFormat`

Comment: I did try the code given in the link. But it's showing only the VALUE Column, not the rest. I have various columns, VALUE and DATE are ones among them. Can you please post a code to it?

Comment: `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat=d}" Header="Date" />` and
`<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amount, StringFormat=C}" Header="Amount" />` according to the link

Comment: Yes I know that. But what about the remaining columns? When I put those two lines, only two columns were showing. I've edited the question, please read again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "VALUE":
            e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = e.PropertyName,
                Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName)
                {
                    StringFormat = "N2"
                }
            };
            break;
        case "DATE":
            e.Column = new DataGridTextColumn
            {
                Header = e.PropertyName,
                Binding = new Binding(e.PropertyName)
                {
                    StringFormat = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern
                }
            };
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works nice! So for this `AutoGeneratingColumn` must be set to True?

Comment: Yes, which it is by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just like VB. You can find [all numeric string formats here (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=VALUE, StringFormat=N2}" Header="Value" />
```

Current culture can be set [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29808486/366064)

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
```

You may also find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6197967/366064) useful

You may also use **converters** for more advanced modifications.

Comment: Please read the edit part in the question. The above solution is working fine. But I have various columns ( like 20+ ), means I have write `DataGridTextColumn` manually for each and every column?!

Comment: @Dante123 Yes that's how it works. you generally have to write one line of `DataGridXColumn` for each column regardless of how you want to format those columns.