# Where should I change/set culture info settings in my WPF app and why? (Must works on all .NET frameworks 4.0 and newer)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, cultureinfo

I'm trying to set up an a culture info for my WPF application and I've found several examples, like:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

And something like this:

```
 protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)

            {

                  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); ;

                  Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); ;



                  FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(

                    typeof(FrameworkElement),

                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(

                          XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));



                  base.OnStartup(e);

           }
```

What is right way to achieve this? And where should I set it? I think setting it everytime windows is opened/loaded is not good idea?

Comment: In your Main() method and at the beginning of every thread that produces output that is culture-sensitive (which might be none). Note that in .Net 4.6 or later, you only need to set it in the main method, but you're using .net 4.0.

Comment: Where? How about the OnStartup method of your App.xaml.cs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Culture (en-IN) Globally in WPF App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454024/setting-culture-en-in-globally-in-wpf-app)

Comment: @mm8 Can you write an example which of this methods above is the right and could you please write how that might look in App.xaml.cs?

Comment: Please see my answer. You can basically just copy the OnStartup method you have posted into the App class in App.xaml.cs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And where should I set it?

Just open the auto-generated `App.xaml.cs` file and override the `OnStartup` method:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); ;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"); ;

        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
          typeof(FrameworkElement),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

This method is called once when the application starts.

Comment: If I apply this, then in my application if I use numbers for calculation, then in right culture 100.56 would be 10056? because that's what I want to set, if users enters 10000 to show it as 10.000

Comment: Please ask a new question and provide an example of your issue if you have one.