# WPF StringFormat on a Run component uses wrong culture

Tags: c#, wpf, currentculture

I have a DateTime property bound to the Text property of a Run element using a StringFormat for ShortDate (StringFormat=d), but it's using en-US culture instead of the system culture (pt-BR). My code looks like this:

```
<TextBlock>
     Next date
     <LineBreak />
     <Run Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" FontWeight="Bold" />
</TextBlock>
```

I used the code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7454053/4905310) to override the culture for all my components.

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-IN");
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

It does work for some components, but it didn't work for that Date format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also override the metadata for `Run` elements:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(Run), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

Or set the `Language` property explicitly:

```
<Run Text="{Binding Date, StringFormat=d}" Language="en-IN" FontWeight="Bold" />
```

A `Run` is not a `FrameworkElement`.