# Setting CurrentCulture AND CurrentUICulture in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo

first off, I'm aware of the general solution to the WPF culture problem: [Setting Culture (en-IN) Globally in WPF App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454024/setting-culture-en-in-globally-in-wpf-app/7454053#7454053)

My question is as follows:
I have an `IValueConverter` for decimal numbers and dates and for them I get the correct `CultureInfo` in the interface call

```
object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

However I also want to convert an Enum value into a UI text. But for this I need `CurrentUICulture` and not `CurrentCulture`. Of course I could use `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` or `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` directly and just ignore the `CultureInfo`.

But that doesn't feel like proper usage of the interface.

Comment: You can directly set `ConverterCulture` in Binding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But that doesn't feel like proper usage of the interface.

It is. An implementation of the `IValueConverter` interface is supposed to convert *values* and hence doesn't care about any `UICulture`.

So getting the `CurrentUICulture` from a source external to the converter is actually a proper use. The `CurrentUICulture` is not passed to the `Convert` method.