# Change keyboard language when application not in focus

Tags: wpf

I am using `SendKeys.SendWait` to send `keyboard` keys to active window and in case the `keyboard` language is non `English` I want to change the `keyboard` language:

```
     var currentInputLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
     var culture = currentInputLang.Culture.Name;
     
     var lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.OfType<InputLanguage>().Where(l
 => l.Culture.Name.StartsWith("en-US")).FirstOrDefault();
     if (lang != null)
         InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
```

So this command works only if my `WPF application` is with focus, Any ideas how to change this `keyboard` language any way ?

**UPDATE**

`XAML`: This is how I start my view model class:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <viewmodel:ViewModelBase/>
</Window.DataContext>

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModelBase()
  {
       MyCommand = new MyCommand(this);
  }  
}
```

My send keys command:

```
public class SaveCommand : ICommand
    {
        public ViewModelBase ViewModel { get; set; }

        public SaveCommand(ViewModelBase viewModel)
        {
            ViewModel = viewModel;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        }
            ChangeKeyboardToEnglish();
            
            // Send keys
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            SendKeys.SendWait(user);
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{TAB}");
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            SendKeys.SendWait(password);
            Thread.Sleep(150);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
        }

        private void ChangeKeyboardToEnglish()
        {
            var currentInputLang = InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage;
            var culture = currentInputLang.Culture.Name;

            var lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.OfType<InputLanguage>().Where(l => l.Culture.Name.StartsWith("en-US")).FirstOrDefault();
            if (lang != null)
                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show the code that reaches this code, how do you get here?

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: How does the user execute this command if the window is not active? Also, when the window is active, you do not verify that your controls are focused. Changing the culture globally can be done on the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7454024/setting-culture-en-in-globally-in-wpf-application