# How to change DatePicker DisplayDate?

Tags: wpf, datepicker

How can i change DatePicker DisplayDate from mm/dd/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the [`SelectedDateFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddateformat.aspx) to 'yyyy-MM-dd'

If you want to set the culture correctly for your entire app, look at this question: [StringFormat Localization issues in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-problem).

You need this code somewhere that runs on startup.

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata( typeof(FrameworkElement), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```