# What CutureInfo does binding use when StringFormat is specified?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is a binding expression I have

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyDateProp, StringFormat=d} />
```

My machine default culture is en-GB. In App.xaml.cs I override `OnStartup` method like below

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
        var newCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU", true);
        newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

I would like text to look like `01 Янв 2001` but it still shows me `1/1/2001`. What culture does binding use and how can I force it to use the culture I want?

Comment: @RohitVats `DateTime` of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem some time ago with WPF controls ignoring culture.  Did you already try changing the following:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
typeof(FrameworkElement),
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
    XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

[Here is a question that talks about it further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-problem/520334#520334)

Also you have StringFormat of d which is the default short date format.  Looks like Windows defaults to dd.MM.yyyy for ru-RU short date.  For this you have two options.

Change the shortdate format for you whole application by specifying the shortdateformat onstartup like your doing.

```
 newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
```

Or changing the date format also on each control for example:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding MyDateProp, StringFormat={}{0:dd MMM yyyy} />
```

In your binding.  If you specify stringformat you will have to do this on every control you want that date format.  So it depends on what your application needs are.

Comment: Now I did it but looks like it is now using pure 'ru-RU' CultureInfo without my fix for ShortDatePattern

Comment: you have d as the stringformat specifier which will show up as the default short date format now that the control is picking up the Russian culture.  D is the long date format.

Comment: yes, I will use it that way. However I wonder if I can set up ShortDateFormat on a CultureInfo level so I don't need to specify exact format every time

Comment: yes specifying shortdatepattern at culturelevel will be a one and done type thing.  It depends on if you need this short date in all your controls in your application or just one...

Answer (score 1):

Since Text property is of type DateTime, textBlock will internally call **`ToString()`** on binded property. So, what you have to do is to set **`ConverterCulture`** property of binding.

```
<TextBlock xmlns:g="clr-namespace:System.Globalization;assembly=mscorlib"
           Text="{Binding MyDateProp, StringFormat=d,
                          ConverterCulture={x:Static g:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"/>
```

Comment: Will it catch the changes to the CultureInfo I introduced? I don't have access to VS right now so I can't check it

Comment: Yes it will. It will pick it from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which you have already set.