# Changing the DateTime format dynamically depending on the selected culture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datetime, localization

I have a label with the content bound to a DateTime object. I want the format of the DateTime to be dynamic, i.e. if the user changes the culture of the program, the format of the DateTime should change accordingly.

I have a SetCulture method which calls the following:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
```

I have tried this for the label:

```
Content="{Binding Model.DateTimeNow, ConverterCulture={x:Static gl:CultureInfo.CurrentCulture}}"
```

However the format does not change even when I set a different culture through the methods above.

How can I achieve a dynamic DateTime format?

Comment: Is `Model.DateTimeNow` a string or a `DateTime` value?

Comment: @Jai: An instance of `DateTime`. Should it be a string instead?

Comment: Try doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-issues-in-wpf/520334#520334)

Comment: @Clemens Yup, actually it would work with an actual converter attached to it.

Comment: The most simple solution seems to be to remove the ConverterCulture from the binding and just set the Window's Language, as shown here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5169037/1136211

Comment: @Clemens: This is not dynamic though, I have to set the Language each time I change the culture.

Comment: @Jai: That won't change it dynamically, and furthermore, I can't call it more than once.

Comment: @gartenriese It works well for me. Of course the binding source property has to be updated to trigger the binding.

Comment: @Clemens: It still doesn't work, even when I'm updating my binding source property after changing the culture.