# DatePicker: month and day wrong way around

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I'm using a DatePicker to display a DateOfBirth property for a given class:

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding SelectedPerson.DateOfBirth }" />
```

I can see from the underlying class (SelectedPerson) that the Date is correct (i.e. day, month & year are correct), yet in the DatePicker the day and the month are reversed.

Thus, 1st February 2016, is displayed as 2nd January 2016 on the DatePicker.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: DateOfBirth is a `DateTIme`? Locale settings can affect format. Looks like NA\EU confusion in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was simple binding to the wrong element.  Should have been SelectedDate, not Text:

```
<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedPerson.DateOfBirth}" />
```

Comment: Nope.  Question showed "DatePicker Text".  Solution shows "DatePicker SelectedDate".  Very easy to make the mistake.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, any bindings which don't explicitly specify a culture will use the invariant culture instead. That means you'll get American date and number formats, ignoring your current regional settings.

This is a long-standing problem, which the WPF team considers to be "by design".

The [standard workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/520334/124386) is to override the property metadata for the `FrameworkElement`'s `Language` property:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
    typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

This needs to be done before you show any UI - usually in the `OnStartup` event.

Unfortunately, this will only solve the problem for elements derived from `FrameworkElement`. The `Run` element, for example, derives from `FrameworkContentElement`, and so it won't be affected by this change. And you can't override the metadata for the `FrameworkContentElement`, as it has already been overridden.

Another alternative is to create and use a custom binding which always initializes the culture to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`:

```
public class CultureBinding : System.Windows.Data.Binding
{
    public CultureBinding(string path) : base(path)
    {
        ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    public CultureBinding()
    {
        ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you'r doing wrong, but as a workaround, you should try the `Date.ToString()` method (docs for this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx)) and if your `SelectedPerson.DateOfBirth` is a `DateTime` object (if it's not, you should consider do that, just saying :p)

**EDIT:** Another thing you should consider is to set the correct culture see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)

Comment: You should *NEVER* convert dates to strings to cover up formatting errors. That simply makes the problem *worse*. Instead of having to deal with one wrong conversion, now you have *two* potentially wrong conversions