# Comma as decimal seperator in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a custom DataGrid which creates a column for each day of a month and binds its content to a given list. The values of the list are doubles.

Now i want to change the input so that the user can write 3,12 instead of 3.12.
I tried to change the cultureinfo which had no effect and also  tried to set the StringFormat for the binding but that did not work aswell. A solution would be to write a converter but i think there may be better methods to achieve this, especially since i do not want to use a specific converter for a more general datagrid.

So my question, how would you achieve this ; what is the best way.

EDIT: I found the solution just after posting my question..

Wpf always uses the "en-US" culture, you can change this behaviour in the whole program by adding

```
            FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
            typeof(FrameworkElement),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

or  just change it for a specific binding like this

```
            Binding contentBinding = new Binding(PATH);
            contentBinding.ConverterCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            textColumn.Binding = contentBinding;
```

Note that you have to take the extra step over binding since textColumn.Binding is not of type Binding but of BindingBase which does not offer the ConverterCulture property anymore.

The answers are from [StringFormat Localization issues in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520115/stringformat-localization-issues-in-wpf/520334#520334).

Comment: Is that specific datagrid the only place you want that logic, or do you want your application to have different culture settings?

Comment: No i do not need multiple cultures but i found a way just after posting this question.. i add the solution to my question.

Answer (score 0):

By this you can set globally for your application to use your windows culture.
So if you have English windows you will use dot and if German windows you will use comma.

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    System.Windows.Markup.XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

keep in mind that this solution set it globally.