# How to bind a datagrid column with StringFormat as N2 with CultureInfo "en-In"?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my wpf datagrid there is a column whose text I want to show as a number but as per Indian format. If I do the below in xaml

`Binding="{Binding Path=Amt, StringFormat=N2}"`

I get the number format as per `en-US` but I want it as per `en-In`.

How can I do that in xaml?

Comment: What about `StringFormat={}{0:N2}` ?  BTW, N2 means 2 decimal places

Comment: @McNets Doesn't work, the values like `134,727.00` should be displayed as `1,34,727.00`

Comment: Then N2 is not your format.

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28366212/3270427

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `Language` property of the `DataGrid` to "en-IN":

```
<DataGrid ... Language="en-IN">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Amt, StringFormat=N2}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or replace the `DataGridTextColumn` with a `DataGridTemplateColumn` if you have different formats for different columns:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Amt, StringFormat=N2}" Language="en-IN" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Amt, StringFormat=N2}" Language="en-IN" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```