# WPF CurrencyNegativePattern

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting

Upon updating my WPF application to net5 I noticed that StringFormat set on a TextBlock seems to use different culture settings than calling ToString from code.  Specifically [CurrencyNegativePattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern?view=net-7.0) is different.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat=C0}"/>
```

with Value=-10 Will format like `-$10`

While

```
(-10).ToString("C0")
```

will format like `($10)`

This app demonstrates the issue:
https://github.com/innominate227/WpfCurrencyNegativePatternIssue

Is there anyway to get WPF to use the same format that is used by the ToString()?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/520334/3390788

Comment: @FrankAlvaro No, I can set the WPF Language property to "en-US", but that still acts differently than new CultureInfo("en-US").

Comment: Further traced this to changes in behavior of XmlLanguage.GetEquivalentCulture starting with net5.0.  Filled a bug report here: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7307

Comment: `(-10).ToString("C0", new CultureInfo("en-US"))` returns "-$10", doesn't it?

Comment: Returns "($10)" for me. https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYAMBYAUBgRjz1QIE4AKCgWgMwEoA6AFQHsBlYMASygHMKAIgDCmQTAAEUAKYB3CaUYBxADasARgEMV3AF6bg3VlEbCIK4BDDSAklABmrIdKjUAqu0H1vAbiA==